# How to convert Vietnamese text to normal text?

Tags: java, android

I have a Vietnamese text like this :

```
String text = "Xin chào Việt Nam";
```

And I want to convert it to normal text. My expect result :

```
String result = " "Xin chao Viet Nam";
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [Normalizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) in `java.text.Normalizer`
. It allows you to map between accented Unicode characters and their decompositions:
it basically converts all accented characters into their deAccented counterparts followed by their combining diacritics. Now you can use a regex to strip off the diacritics.

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.out.println(deAccent("Xin chào Việt Nam"));
        }

        public static String deAccent(String str) {
            String nfdNormalizedString = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD); 
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
            return pattern.matcher(nfdNormalizedString).replaceAll("");
        }
```

Comment: but input with String "đi", deAccent("đi") given the result is "đi". It does not effectively in normalize text

Comment: @VanThaoNguyen did you find any solution to solve your problem? I'm facing the same issue, please share it if you solved it.

Comment: @Na Pro: In the production, I used the mapping from character to character and it work well as well as ensure performance. Examples you can find in the link below: https://quyetdo289.wordpress.com/2015/05/17/loai-bo-dau-tieng-viet-trong-java/

Comment: @VanThaoNguyen: Thanks, I'm using the same solution :D

Comment: @VanThaoNguyen, you can simply resolve this problem by replace all character "đ" by "d"

Answer (score 2):

for those who are looking for:

```
    public String toKhongDau(String str) {
    try {
        String temp = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
        return pattern.matcher(temp).replaceAll("").toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "-").replaceAll("đ", "d");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: This function does not convert the letter "đ" to "d" and "Đ" to "D".
Refer to this solution may solve that problem: https://riptutorial.com/android/example/32758/chuy-n-chu-i-ti-ng-vi-t-thanh-chu-i-khong-d-u

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is converting each char to HEX and replace it with another HEX. It's because there are 2 Unicode typing:

1. Composite Unicode
2. Precomposed Unicode

For example "Ồ" written by `Composite Unicode` is different from "Ồ" written by `Precomposed Unicode`. You can copy my sample chars and convert them to see the difference.

- In `Composite Unicode`, "Ồ" is combined from 2 char: `Ô` (`U+00d4`)
  and `̀` (`U+0300`)
- In `Precomposed Unicode`, "Ồ" is single char
  (`U+1ED2`)

I have developed this feature for some banks to convert the info before sending it to core-bank (usually don't support Unicode) and faced this issue when the end-users use multiple Unicode typing to input the data. So I think, converting to HEX and replace it is the most reliable way.